# Function return 3 dimensional array, how can I get 1 dimensional array?

Tags: arrays

```
def GradientDescentMulti(x_train,y_train, theta, alpha, num_iters):
 J_history=[]
 for iter in range (1,151):
  h= x_train.dot(theta)
  error=h-y_train
  theta_change = (1./m) * alpha * (x_train.T .dot(error))
  theta=theta-theta_change
  cost_history=(1./(2*m)) * ((error.T) .dot (error))
  J_history.append(cost_history)
 return J_history
```

I have the above mentioned function. I call the function below

```
 theta = np.zeros((n,1))
 num_iters=150
 alpha = 0.01
 history = GradientDescentMulti(x_train[:10000],y_train[:10000], theta, alpha, num_iters)
 print(history)
```

Then I get 3 dimensional arrays like the picture. I need 1 dimensional array so that I can plot 1 to 150 in the x axis and the numbers from the history array in y axis. What can I do to get 1 dimensional array from the function?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ics2y.png)

Comment: use `np.reshape()`

Comment: Reshaping actually worked. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: post the code below as answer and accept it, so that future readers will have the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I got the 3 dimensional array as the output in history. I applied the following reshape to turn it into a 1 dimensional array

```
history =np.array(history)
history_reshape=np.reshape(history, (150,))
```